# What's the info plist key for UIApplicationShortcutIcon(systemImageName:)?

Tags: ios, uiapplicationshortcutitem

I couldn't find it in the document.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post text as actual text. And what key are you asking about? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: That's exactly why I attached the screenshots. The existing keys listed in the doc are listed in the 2nd screenshot.